# ActiveMQ, STOMP, Java example

Tags: activemq-classic, failover, stomp

Can anyone point me to decent example where Java stomp client is used to connect to ActiveMQ.
Also I am interested in following:

- Is failover supported over stomp?
- How to create durable subscription?
- Does stomp support asynchronous messaging? Examples? I think I have to implement MessageListener interface for it, but I wasn't able to find example for this.

Comment: Is there any reason you want to use STOMP in Java? You can use the normal ActiveMQ Java client if there are no cross language clients.

Comment: There are cross language clients involved.
So, I'd like to see how stomp client will work performance-wise.

Comment: STOMP being designed for plain text, I think it's performance might not be better than native Java library for AMQ but you can test it. See http://stomp.github.io/implementations.html and try one of the implementations.

Comment: Yeah, I've been to that page. Seems like Gozirra is a dead project since URL doesn't work and Stampy's examples are not clear.

Comment: I have found example at 
https://github.com/bpardee/jruby-activemq/blob/master/apache-activemq-5.5.1/example/src/StompExample.java 
and it uses classes from activemq-stomp-5.9.1.jar  but it looks like it is not asynchronous consumption of the messages (StompFrame message = connection.receive();)

Comment: Yes. ActiveMQ isn't actively developing STOMP APIs and they don't have support for asynch interface and failover. They don't even support STOMP 1.2

Comment: I shouldn't bother than.. this is what I found on activeMQ web site:

"Since version 5.2, there is a simple Java Stomp API distributed with ActiveMQ. Note that this API is provided purely for testing purposes and you should always consider using standard JMS API from Java instead of this one." 

I also checked distribution, it has /example folder with example on how stomp API could be used..

Comment: Did you look at http://activemq.apache.org/apollo/documentation/stomp-manual.html?

Comment: @Buchi current ActiveMQ seems to implement STOMP 1.2 fully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use STOMP from Java then you could look at [StompJMS](https://github.com/fusesource/stompjms) which maps quite a bit of the JMS API to STOMP.  It doesn't support failover but there aren't a lot of stomp client's that do.  When using Java you are better off to use the native JMS client from the ActiveMQ broker as it is going to be the most robust and feature complete client library you will find.